# Incorrect syntax when using MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I use the `MERGE` statement, I get an "invalid syntax" error:

```
MERGE ResponsibleLawyers AS RL
USING @tempPerson AS TP ON RL.ResponsibleLawyerID = TP.ResponsibleLawyerID

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET RL.FirstName = TP.FirstName, 
            RL.LastName = TP.LastName, 
            RL.AccountName = TP.AccountName, 
            RL.EmailAddress = TP.EmailAddress, 
            RL.Region = TP.Region, 
            RL.Active = TP.Active 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY RL THEN
    INSERT (ResponsibleLawyerID, FirstName, LastName, AccountName, EmailAddress, Region, Active) 
    VALUES (TP.ResponsibleLawyerID, TP.FirstName, TP.LastName, TP.AccountName, TP.EmailAddress, TP.Region, TP.Active)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE
```

I get an error "Invalid syntax" beside "RL". I'm using 110 compatibility level on SQL Server 2012. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY RL THEN
```

Comment: I think it is the `RL.` after the `SET`.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

I think `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY RL THEN` should be `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN`. You use `SOURCE` & `TARGET` here, not the table alias. The confusion may arise because many examples use `SOURCE` & `TARGET` as the table alias.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Omega did this answer your question?